# How can I delete local realm in macOS?

Tags: macos, realm

I want to debug my app from scratch so I need to remove its' Realm file. How do I do that in macOS?

(deleting DerivedData, keychain and cleaning did not work)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a button with the following code to remove Realm data in Swift 4

```
func doDelete() {
    let realmURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
    let realmURLs = [
        realmURL,
        realmURL.appendingPathExtension("lock"),
        realmURL.appendingPathExtension("note"),
        realmURL.appendingPathExtension("management")
    ]
    for URL in realmURLs {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

alternately you can manually remove the database portion using the finder by deleting the folder:

```
~/Library/Application Support/com.company_name.app_name
```

the bundle identifier (found in the General settings for your app in Xcode) is the last part of the path. The path may vary depending on sandboxing, iOS/macOS and the bundle name.

**Edit**

With sandboxing on the location is

```
~/Library/Containers/com.company_name.app_name
```

Comment: I have removed the app from this location (`~/Library...`) but running from Xcode still shows me the data. It's only stored at this location if the app was properly installed.

Comment: @gerbil Did you mean that you deleted the file while the application was running? Or did you delete the file after exiting and re-launch again? If it is the former, even if you delete the file while opening, it will not actually be deleted until the file is closed. That is expected behavior.

Comment: I deleted after exiting. This is not the location for apps that run from Xcode.

Comment: @gerbil Yes, it is the correct path with sandboxing off.

Comment: For more info please see [Service Not Running](https://forums.realm.io/t/xcode-9-swift-4-failed-to-connect-service-not-running/541)

Answer (score 0):

Realm data can be removed at this folder:

~/Library/Containers/com.company_name.app_name

Comment: The location I mentioned in my answer is correct when sandboxing is turned off (at stated). With sandboxing on it's stored in a different location, updated my answer and provided a link to some additional information.